# Replace 1 or more instances of quoted GUIDs in JS string with unquoted versions

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

**PROBLEM**

I have a string (in **JavaScript**) which may or may not contain one or more **GUIDs** at various places. These **GUIDs** are surrounded by single quotes. I need to remove the quotes.

**WHAT I HAVE SO FAR**

**Regex to match GUIDs with single quotes:**

```
var guid = /('[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12}')/ig;
```

**a way to replace all single and double quotes:**

```
myString = myString.replace(/["']/g, ""); // I actually don't need the double quote here...
```

But I am not sure how to replace each instance of a matched **GUID** with single quotes with the same **GUID** without the quotes... while still keeping any other single quotes in the string.

I am guessing I probably need to get all matches, loop through each of them and do a replacement.. in **pseudo code**:

```
var matches = myString.matches(guid);
foreach (var match in matches)
{
    myString = myString.replace(match.value, match.value.replace("'", ""));
}
```

Can someone give me the above in **jQuery** or **plain JS**? Also, if there's a much simpler way to do it, that would be even better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're very close. Change that regex to include a capture group *without* the `'` in it:

```
var guid = /'([0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12})'/ig;
// Change   ^^------------------------------------------------------------^^
```

then:

```
str = str.replace(guid, "$1");
```

`$1` = the first capture group. Because of the `g` on your regex, that will replace all occurrences in the string.

**Live example:**

```js
var guid = /'([0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12})'/ig;
var str = "Testing '00b3dada-88d7-482a-b082-039cc7153023' and '30378f4e-889c-4a9a-854c-daa304969246' and '413db223-7c02-4f95-a994-8aaaad48a245'";
snippet.log("Before: " + str);
str = str.replace(guid, "$1");
snippet.log("After: " + str);
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: It works perfectly, thank you!! I will accept the answer as soon as it lets me (5 minutes).. you answered so fast I can't even accept it yet..  :-D  nice one!

Comment: @Matt: Well, you did most of the work. I just picked up an assist. :-)